# How to change background of header and rows in Jqgrid?

Tags: css, jqgrid

I need to change the background of the header and also the rows of a Jquery grid. I have tried to change several css classes but I dont get the result I want.

Comment: Can you give us some more information, please?
Like : The html-code you are trying to change, the css-code that applies to the pieces that you want to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// this changes the background image of the header
.ui-jqgrid .ui-widget-header{
   background-image: url(myBackground.jpg) repeat-x !important;
}

// this changes the background color of every row in a jqgrid
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

**Note:** `!important` might not be necessary.

Also make sure that your css file is loaded **after** jqgrid's css file!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="ui.jqgrid.css" />
<!-- load jqgrid css first then your css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="mystyle.css" />
```

Comment: tried to use this... its working for row but not for header... how can we change for header ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//for changing colour of titlebar
#list .ui-jqgrid-titlebar {
background:blue;
}
//for changing header
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th{
background: blue
}
```